# Finding variants of a string (only deletion, no transposition)

Tags: java, string, word-processor

Given a string, I want to find all variants without transposition, only deletion. For example, given the string:

```
helloo
```

The list of variants would be as follows (separated by white space).

```
helloo hello heloo helo
```

My solution so far is to move through each character, and then if the current character matches the next character, recursively try the original and the deleted character version, as follows.

```
// takes String with at most two consecutive characters of any character, 
// and returns an Iterable of all possible variants (e.g. hheello -> heello, hhello, ...)
private static Iterable<String> findAllVariants(String word) {
    StringBuilder variant = new StringBuilder(word);
    Queue<String> q = new LinkedList<String>();
    findAllVariants(word, variant, 0, q);
    return q;
}

// helper method
private static void findAllVariants(String word, StringBuilder variant, int currIndex, Queue<String> q) {
    if (currIndex == variant.length() - 1) q.add(variant.toString());

    for (int i = currIndex; i < variant.length() - 1; i++) {
        char thisChar = variant.charAt(i);
        char nextChar = variant.charAt(i+1);
        if (thisChar == nextChar) {
            // get all variants with repeat character
            findAllVariants(word, variant, i+1, q);

            // get all variants without repeat character;
            variant = variant.deleteCharAt(i);
            findAllVariants(word, variant, i, q);
        }
    }
}
```

However, I end up getting a large number of copies of answers, and none of others. When I do my algorithm on paper, it seems correct. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something along the lines of the following code will enable you to get all possibilities (remember to add `word` itself if needed). The idea is to retreive all possibilities for removing one char (e.g. `hello` results in `ello hllo helo hell`). These results can in turn be used to get the possibilities for removing two chars (remove one char again). Resulting in `llo elo ell` for `ello` and so on...

```
List<String> getPossibilities(String word) {
    int removeChars = word.length() - 1;
    List<String> possibilities = new ArrayList();
    List<String> options = Arrays.asList(word);
    for(int i = 0; i <= removeChars; i++) {
        List<String> results = new ArrayList();
        for(String option : options) {
          for(String result : removeOneChar(option)) {
                if(!results.contains(result)) {
                    results.add(result);
                }
            }
        }
        possibilities.addAll(results);
        options = results;
    }
    return possibilities;
}

private static List<String> removeOneChar(String word) {
    List<String> results = new ArrayList();
    for(int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
        int secondPart = i + 2;
        if(secondPart <= word.length()) {
            results.add(
                    word.substring(0, i) 
                    + word.substring(i + 1, word.length()));
        }
        else {
            results.add(
                    word.substring(0, i));
        }
    }
    return results;
}
```

Notice the `if(!contains(result))` in order to prevent any duplicates.

**Note** I've used `substring()` to accomplish this, you're approach with `removeCharAt()` is a another good option. You could run some tests to see which performs better to decide which one to use. Notice using the latter could possibly remove the need of the `if` in the `private` method.

Comment: Two notes of confusion on your code: one, where does the recursion occur? And two, why do you convert word into a list, and then iterate through it? What does that do?

Comment: You're right, the term recursion has been typed before I changed the code. Will correct that! I convert word to a list for the first iteration, following iterations (nested loops) will have more `options`. E.g. your word is `hello`, on next iteration options will contain `ello hllo helo hell` (passed as a list). Next iteration this loop will be used to get all possibilities in deleting chars from `ello`, `hllo`, `helo`, `hell` and so on until strings of a single char (`int removeChars`) are left (last iteration of the outer loop).

Comment: Interestingly, your code only partially solves the problem. Also, it does not produce a set of unique results, but instead many repeats.

Comment: Got it! Your solution works perfectly, save for a few repeats, which could be fixed using a set or the like. However, the line `for (String result : removeOneChar(word)` needs to be changed to `for (String result : removeOneChar(option)`.

Comment: So, I've been looking at this again, and I'm starting to doubt the correctness of this algorithm. Only the first two characters actually end up getting down to one character, and the rest stay at two, with the last character remaining at three. Any ideas?

Comment: @cjspook You're absolutely right. Wrote this without an IDE, fixed it accordingly, tested and fully functioning!

Answer (score 0):

I'd use rather different algorithm: I'd find all repetitions (ll) (oo) (lll) (ooo) etc.., keep an array describing their positions in the text, and the count of characters per each repetition.
e.g Array A = 
[l|2]
[o|2]
.
.
.

Then I'd say have second array with initial count zero and increase there the count and print out all permutations:

Array B = 
[l|1]
[o|1]
==> prints helo

Step 2: (increment count)
B = 
[l|2]
[o|1]
==> prints hello

Step 3: 
B = 
[l|3] ==> bigger than max,so reset it to 0, and increment the second cell now, so it becomes:
B = 
[l|1]
[o|2]
==> prints heloo

Step 4: (increment first elem again)
[l|2] ==> not bigger than max, so no overflow, so keeping it that way
[o|2]
==> prints helloo

Comment: This seems to be a similar approach to what I have now, just reinterpreted.